# modbus rtu on nodered docker

Tags: docker-compose, node-red, modbus

How can I configure serial communication (modbus rtu), specifically with an Arduino device, within a Node-RED Docker container using the provided docker-compose.yml file?

Here is a snippet from my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  node-red:
    image: nodered/node-red:latest
    environment:
      - TZ=Asia/Jakarta
      - NODE_RED_ADMIN_PW=${NODE_RED_PW_1}
    container_name: secure_noderedx
    ports:
      - "1880:1880"
      - "1883:1883"
    command:
      - "/settings/settings.js"
    volumes:
      - volume_server_1:/data
      - ./settings/settings.js:/data/settings.js
    devices:
      - /dev/ttyACM0  # <-- Arduino device
    env_file:
      - .env
```

I have connected my Arduino device to /dev/ttyACM0, but it seems like Node-RED running inside the Docker container is not able to access it. Is there a specific configuration or step that I am missing to enable serial communication between the Arduino and Node-RED within a Docker container?

Any help or guidance on how to properly configure serial communication in a Dockerized Node-RED environment would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to mount any devices into the container for them to be accessible, e.g. in this case you will need to bind mount the `/dev/ttyACM0` device into the container on the same path.

You will also need to ensure that the device is readable by the `node-red` user inside the container.

The `/dev/ttyACM0` device is most likely owned by the `dialout` group on the host machine so you should add the following to your service:

```
group_add:
  - dialout
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#group_add

Comment: many thanks, now it works